# Can not fill or paint on layers in Gimp

Tags: gimp, layers, pixel

I am working on an image in gimp that has multiple layers.

I just added a new layer, and am now observing some odd behavior.

I have three layers, A , B , C. C is the newly created layer.

For some reason, on layers B and C, I can not manipulate the pixels with any of the tools. For example I can not fill, or paint with paintbrush, or erase with the eraser. There is not X cursor, or any kind of cursor indicating that I can not perform the operation.

On Layer A, I can manipulate pixels, but only the non-transparent pixels.

I am not sure what more pertinent info I can give about the current image/configuration.

What could be causing the described scenario?

Comment: Check the [alpha channel lock](https://docs.gimp.org/en/images/dialogs/lock-alpha.png) is not engaged on the layers you are trying to edit.

Comment: I can confirm that I have checked that, it is not the problem.

Comment: Check the brush mode is set to normal, the layer blending modes are set to normal, a contrasting foreground colour is chosen, brush opacity is 100%, all layer blending modes set to normal, Brush Dynamics set to off, layers above may be hiding layers below . . . etc, etc.  The list of possible problems is almost endless. It's hard to answer this definitively, except by making guesses.

Answer (score 1):

For A check the alpha-lock.

[image]

For B and C, check the pixel lock.

[image]

See [here](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-dialogs-structure.html#gimp-layer-dialog-lock-alpha-button) for details.